# Regex to pick out two urls with no seperating character

Tags: regex, url, expression

I'm looking for a regex that can pick out two urls that have no separating character. I have a regex which correctly idtentifies urls in the way I would want it to but it fails if the urls are touching.

[CURRENT REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/cv72Ih/1)

It's for a chat service, for instance in the message
"Hey checkout these links www.google.comwww.apple.com", I want to be able to identify both links as two separate links.

I'm looking for a REGEX solution idealy, but I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: how are you going to split "amazon.co" and "mmm.com" once they are attached?

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable anchors I could identify are the protocol part and the `www` subdomain in conjunction with a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat):

```
((https?:\/\/(www)?)|www\.)(?:(?!https?:\/\/|www\.).)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cv72Ih/2)